# Error deploying or retrieving source

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I have newly created a project then created a random LWC page and right click on it and deploy and it is giving me below error

> The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a
> package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add
> this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or
> retrieve a different file or directory. For details about
> sfdx-project.json, see:
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm
> You can run SFDX: Deploy Source to Org only on a source file or
> directory.

Below is my sfdx-project.json

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "myproject",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you add your folder structure as well?

Comment: I have added the screenshot, it is a newly created project no change from side at all related to file system.

Comment: The error you recd mostly it occurs when you mention something in manifest>package.xml and it's not present in the folder structure. Pls check that file once. Also check if LWC folder has something which is supposed to get deployed.

Comment: I can deploy and retrieve from package.xml, the problem comes when I try to deploy an individual component by right clicking and deploy

Comment: oh, click on that LWC folder than individual js/html/xml file.

Comment: yes correct, right click on html and then hit deploy giving this error

Comment: What is your SFDX CLI version?

Comment: @gs650x - It doesn't work with individual file part as per my experience. Use folder right-click way to deploy same.

Comment: folder right click also not working

Comment: @PhilW this is the current version installed sfdx-cli/7.158.1 win32-x64 node-v16.15.1

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether you upgraded the CLI recently? See [this other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380225/unable-to-deploy-code-using-vscode). Two independent users having similar issues makes me think there's an environmental issue. It could be the CLI having a bug, or could be due to a problem on the org side, of course.

Comment: This is reported by several users.See  https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4261. Try downgrading the "Salesforce CLI Integration" extension version.

Comment: you are awesome! thank you so much, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is related to the recently published version v55.4.0 of the Salesforce Extension for VS Code.

Multiple users are impacted by this.You can follow https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4261 for updates.

The workaround for now, would be to downgrade the "Salesforce CLI Integration" extension version.

I will keep this thread updated as I have more inputs from our concerned Salesforce product development team.

Update:
As a fix, v55.4.1 of the Salesforce Extension for VS Code has been published.  See the release notes here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/releases/tag/v55.4.1

Comment: Hi @Swetha, I am getting the similar issue however ,the above mentioned solution is not working for me. I'd appreciate if you could spend some time on this, below is the URL of my question - 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/411433/vs-code-retrieve-and-deploy-commands-are-not-working-from-command-palette-right