# Unable to deploy code using VSCode

Tags: vs-code

I am getting following error while deploying code from VSCode.

> Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you
> tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's
> specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your
> "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or
> directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see:
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

Retrieving of code into VSCode seems to work fine but deployment throws this error.

Here is what my sfdx-project.json looks like

```
 {
      "packageDirectories": [
        {
          "path": "force-app",
          "default": true
        }
      ],
      "name": "XXXXXX2022",
      "namespace": "",
      "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com",
      "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"
    }
```

It was working fine till last week, suddenly today i seem to get this error.
Anybody having similar issue?

Comment: Similar question thread is here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380221/error-deploying-or-retrieving-source

Comment: What are you trying to deploy?

Comment: Did you update your SFDX CLI version since yesterday (when this was working)?

Comment: @PhilW there were a bunch of updates which was done yesterday

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the CLI version (if you updated it since yesterday) to see if that is the problem?

Comment: @PhilW Looks like an issue with the latest release. Others have reported the same on githib

Comment: See github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4261

Comment: @PhilW downgrade worked

Comment: I am checking with our concerned salesforce product team for an update on this and will keep you posted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the most recent Salesforce CLI Integration Extension for VS Code on Windows (v55.4.0)

To resolve, go to your extensions, go to Salesforce CLI Integration, click the drop down next to Uninstall, and click "Install another version". Install the previous version (55.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

As a fix, v55.4.1 of the Salesforce Extension for VS Code has been published.  See the release notes here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/releases/tag/v55.4.1

Comment: Thanks for keeping us posted