# VS Code Retrieve and Deploy Commands are not working from command palette/right click menu while working great from Terminal commands

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code

**Getting below error when I Retrieve or Deploy any component in my VS Code -**

Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

**Retrieve/Deploy are working fine by using below commands from Terminal -**

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --sourcepath .\force-app\main\default\lwc\helloWorld
sfdx force:source:retrieve --sourcepath .\force-app\main\default\lwc\helloWorld
```

I think the problem started after an update in VS Code extensions "Salesforce CLI Integration" or/and "Salesforce Extension Pack", however I revert the previous version still not able to resolve.

Below is my sfdx-project.json

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0"
}
```

I appreciate for any help, thank you.

Comment: are you working behind a company proxy?

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by that?

Comment: Is  this your company org and do you use VPN to do your work?

Comment: I am not using VPN.

Comment: I had the same issue but running the below command from the terminal worked for me.
`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default` - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IFKyQAO

Comment: Also, Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911955/error-deploying-or-retrieving-source-the-file-or-directory-isnt-in-sfdx-projec

Comment: thanks for your response Tushar, when I run this command, it start deploying the entire package to my connected org.